# How do I represent a pointer to the beginning of my address space?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, language-agnostic, embedded

Let's consider some strange hypothetical embedded system where I need to produce and use a pointer that points to, or might point to, the first byte of my address space. That is, a pointer equal to zero. Not a NULL pointer, but a perfectly valid zero pointer, which might get dereferenced or incremented or treated as an array just like any other pointer. How would I do this in languages that treat a NULL pointer as special, but don't have a real NULL type?

Comment: Your "strange hypothetical embedded system" should come with some tools, like a software development kit. Check the hypothetical documentation.

Comment: There's nothing hypothetical about it, you can map 0 to an address with `mmap()` on Linux and `VirtualAlloc` on Windows...

Comment: What's wrong with `(void*)0`?

Comment: What might work is casting an integer variable that happens to have the value 0 to a pointer.

Comment: @KeithRandall That produces a null pointer per the standard, you mustn't use a literal 0.

Comment: @Benj: You can try, but the OS isn't obliged to do so.  On Linux, `mmap(2)` will refuse to map any addresses below the value in the pseudofile `/proc/sys/vm/mmap_min_addr` (see [this blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/ksplice/entry/much_ado_about_null_an1) for more background).

Comment: @DanielFischer: I don't see how you are going to avoid violating the standard if you have memory you need to access at address 0.

Comment: @Benj: And if you try to VirtualAlloc NULL, then VirtualAlloc will decide where to allocate the memory.

Comment: @AdamRosenfield It looks as though some older Linux distros let you do this: http://www.sharms.org/blog/2009/07/fun-stuff/

Comment: @KeithRandall Why? The standard prohibits dereferencing a null pointer, not necessarily a pointer with all bits zero.

Comment: @NicolBolas I recall Mark Russinovich talking about this, there's a way to trick `VirtualAlloc`, but I forget the details and can't find them now.

Comment: @NicolBolas You just pass `(void*)1`, works because NT will round down to the nearest allocation boundary.

Comment: @DanielFischer: The standard doesn't prohibit dereferencing NULL, it just says it is undefined behavior.  Likely his system defines it to be reading memory location 0 (unless NULL is mapped to some other bit pattern).  The part of the standard you're going to violate is the requirement that all other pointers are != to NULL (which just means you have to be careful about comparing this pointer against NULL).

Comment: @KeithRandall The UB is what I meant with prohibit, bad choice of words, agreed. But the standard doesn't say that a null pointer points to memory address 0, in fact, if 0 is a valid address, it can't. A null pointer may be one with bit representation `0x55..55` (appropriate number of hex digits) if the implementation decides so. So in that case, there'd be no problem having a pointer with all bits zero pointing to memory address 0.

Comment: @DanielFischer: Right, I guess the question is whether his NULL bit representation is 0 or not.  I highly suspect that it is.  In which case, my point stands.  If his NULL is some other thing, then you're right.

Comment: @KeithRandall If `NULL` is all bits zero, and the bits of pointers map directly to addresses, then 0 isn't a valid memory address, as far as C is concerned. If 0 is a valid address, at least one of the conditions must not hold.

Comment: @DanielFischer, no system I am aware of will put the heap or stack at memory location 0, so in general it's still a reserved address; you're likely to know if you're doing some special memory manipulation that might leave you with a pointer to 0. As far as undefined behavior goes, remember that one possible result is to do exactly what you'd expect. Since compilers never make you pay for what you don't need, it's unlikely that they treat address 0 as a special case.

Comment: @MarkRansom I don't know one either, but the question starts "Let's consider some strange hypothetical embedded system".

Comment: @MarkRansom: It's not uncommon for compilers to treat `NULL` specially in the optimiser, though - for example in a code path that dereferences a pointer the optimiser can assume that the pointer will always compare unequal to `NULL`.

Answer (score 5):

The whole "NULL pointer having a special value different than 0 treated special" is a possibility on some rare old machines, but in practice, your NULL/0 pointer pointing to adress 0 will have value 0 and really point to address 0 on most machines.

It will be perfectly dereferenceable, and you can write on that address if there is some memory mapped to this area.

I used to have that on an embedded platform I worked with. So I used to put a debugger watchpoint on address 0, since all accesses to this area were NULL-pointers dereferences. Caught some errors that way ^^

Answer (score 3):

In most architectures there's nothing special about a NULL pointer at all, it's just a regular pointer with an address of 0. If you're working with an embedded system that has actual memory there, it should work properly. The only problem comes if you try to check the pointer for a null value, so don't do that.

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, register definitions (pointer to a specific address) are written (in my copy of CodeWarrior) as:

```
#define REGISTER_XYZ      (*(vuint32 *)(0x40100000))
```

Note the **vuint**, as it's a volatile location (may change outside of our control) which may or may not be relevant to you.

And replace 0x40100000 with your address of choice, natch.