# What is a vuint in C, and why is it in my microcontroller?

Tags: c, types, microcontroller, volatile, memory-address

I'm flipping through some C header files for a microcontroller, and I keep seeing register addresses initialized as vuint.  I haven't come across this data type before, so I did a bit of searching, with no real results.  The closest I got was from https://stackoverflow.com/a/12855989, which tells me that v stands for "volatile".  So, I have volatile unsigned ints holding hardware register addresses.  As in, I have a data type that explicitly states "This address is subject to change", representing registers that are hard-wired, and cannot change, like, ever.  Is my understanding of vuint incorrect?  If not, why are we representing addresses this way?

Comment: There will be a `typedef` for it somewhere. Find that and it might become clearer.

Comment: One way to figure out that type is to preprocess your source file.  For example with gcc you can use the "-E" option to preprocess-only, and the output will be the preprocessed source file.  Then you can search through the output to see whether vuint is a typedef or a #define.

Comment: its nice to see a discussion of volatile in its correct / original use case, as opposed to the long discussions about threading, multi processor .....

Comment: plus, these are not ints holding the address of external registers. These are ints mapped onto specific hardware addresses, probably a port or a register in an IO controller; thus reading that int measn reading that register or port

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory mapped registers are set as volatile because the values in them can change for external reasons (hardware interrupt, etc...) that the compiler does not know about. This means that the compiler should avoid certain optimizations and ensure that reads to the address are actually made (rather than being optimized out for cached values, etc...).

Quick example, memory mapped register that contains some flags.

```
read flags
set bit in flags
interrupt sets another bit
<compiler optimizes and cached flags from before>
read flags <contains incorrect cached value>
```

Comment: Cool.  I hadn't been thinking of it in the context of well-meant, incorrect optimizations.  Makes me wonder now if some of the bugs I was experiencing way back when I was first learning micros may have been due to using normal uints.

Comment: It's possible. This is only for memory mapped hardware registers really. There aren't many other use cases for volatile (aside from say cache coherence on some RISC processors and a couple of other very technical things).

Answer (score 2):

I think you are misinterpreting the type.  It is mostly likely a pointer to a volatile unsigned integer, indicating the unsigned integer is volatile and not the pointer.  This is typical when describing hardware registers via structs.  Each of the struct members will be a volatile unsigned integer and somewhere there will be a base address defined that indicates where the registers start in the memory map.

Comment: You're quite correct.  Glancing back at the header, it's a pointer.  Example line: #define MCF_PIT0_PCSR (*(vuint16*)(&__IPSBAR[0x150000]))